# Android Device ScreenSize Problem

Tags: android-layout

in my Home Screen i have set one image as background, And set Three Image Button on That Background Image at Bottom of layout. it(Three Image Button) seems perfect in 480x854 screen Device but not in 240x320 Screen size of device. My XML Layout That I use is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:background="@drawable/inscreen">
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/clip"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                   android:layout_marginBottom="95dip"
                   android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
                   android:src="@drawable/selector"/>
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/catagoryvid"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                   android:layout_marginBottom="55dip"
                   android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
                   android:src="@drawable/selector1"/>
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/search"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                   android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
                   android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
                   android:src="@drawable/selector2"/>
    </FrameLayout>
```

Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: Add your XML Layout details for more understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use relative layout for handling such type of problem, In which you can put the controls relatively regardless of screen size.

Comment: what you have tried can paste here so that I may help you in that if any